# How do I remove all SAS formats from a sas7bdat table?

Tags: sas

I have a sas7bdat table that contains format information but I do not have the formats, so lots of the data appears as `*` and doesn't make much sense. I know the informat data that lies beneath is there — how can I remove all formats from the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another way in addition to @JustinDavies's answer that is to use `PROC DATASETS` procedure.

Adapted from the SAS documentation: [Example 1: Removing All Labels and Formats in a Data Set](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003185567.htm)

```
proc datasets lib=<your library> memtype=data nolist;
   modify <your dataset>; 
     attrib _all_ label=' '; 
     attrib _all_ format=;
     attrib _all_ informat=;
run;
```

The advantage in using `PROC DATASETS` is that it modifies the dataset's metadata in-place - i.e., it is not going to create  a new dataset as suggested in the other answer to this question. That feature could be of advantage if your dataset is large.

Comment: Thanks. This is potentially really useful : )

Answer (score 1):

The following code will strip all formatting from the table `FORMATTED_TABLE` and create a new table named `UNFORMATTED_TABLE`

```
data UNFORMATTED_TABLE;
  set FORMATTED_TABLE;
  format _all_;
run;
```

Comment: @Oops didn't realise that you & the questioner were the same.

Comment: It's worth adding that you may need to set `OPTIONS nofmterr;` to read a data table when you don't have the formats available.